# Crash on class instantiation with variable stored property and default value, SKLabelNode, Swift iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift, sprite-kit

This is a new crash I get with iOS 8.1, XCode 6.1, iPhone 5 a1528 which did not exist on iOS 8.0, XCode 6.0, iPhone 5 a1528.

The offending line of code is:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "American Typewriter")
    ...
```

The relevant backtrace is:

```
frame #0: 0x1fe0c08c dyld`dyld_fatal_error
frame #1: 0x1fe0e902 dyld`dyld::halt(char const*) + 74
frame #2: 0x1fe0eb1a dyld`dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 278
frame #3: 0x300e0094 libdyld.dylib`dyld_stub_binder + 20
frame #4: 0x000c5dcc Pizza Slice`Pizza_Slice.GameScene.init (size=CoreGraphics.CGSize at 0x001ea3f0, self=0x16d034f0)(size : C.CGSize) -> Pizza_Slice.GameScene + 156 at GameScene.swift:16
```

And the only visible error from `dyld_fatal_error` is:

> EXC_BREAKPOINT

Is anyone else seeing similar new errors in their projects like this?

Comment: Always use latest Xcode version

Comment: Agreed. Using latest version XCode 6.1 and getting crash. Was no crash in the past when latest version was XCode 6.0 and I was using that.

Comment: What happen if you put a breakpoint just after that line ? Did you print the label value ?

Comment: Breaking on that line does not allow step into because the items in the backtrace are all Apple's code, not mine